# Providing configuration for some named WCF services in <services> while leaving the rest defaulted?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a number of WCF services (10+) which work alright, but I have one Document service which needs higher limits.

I can specify a nameless HTTP Binding and that works ok, but will apply the settings to every service

```
<binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
</binding>
```

However if give this one a named (eg name="LargeHttpBinding") and try to specify the single service in the services block...

```
<services>
  <service name="My.Service.Name">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeHttpBinding" contract="My.Service.IName" />
  </service>
</services>
```

... then nothing will work, presumably as it now means every service would have to be individually named in services?
Is there any way to have one service listed in  and have the result default as normal, or would they all have to be listed in  if at least one is?

Comment: Would much better if you provide whole config file with services, behaviors and bindings

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit confused, but couldn't you just have two bindings -- the nameless binding to be used as the default, and the named binding to be applied specifically to the service that needs it?

```
<binding messageEncoding="Text">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" />
</binding>
<binding name="SpecificBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
</binding>
```

This way, the nameless binding would be used as the default, and named binding would only apply to the service that specifies that binding configuration name.

Comment: But to do that I need to specify the Service within the Services block - and then we are unable to hit any that _aren't_ named. The issue then is with the Services block, not the actual bindings.

I would be looking something like a <service name="*" /> (which doesn't work)